# InternetExplorer DocumentCompleteEventHandler not firing in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am new to C#, I am writing code to open an IEBrowser and do some stuff once its loaded.

If you see the code in Main below

Here is my code :

```
public delegate void DocumentCompleteEventHandler(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE);
class Program{
    private static string m_autoLoginFormContents = null;
    private static SHDocVw.InternetExplorer m_autologinIEWindow;
    static SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler m_AutoLoginDocCompleteHandler;
    private static SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler m_documentCompleteEventHandler;
    public static event DocumentCompleteEventHandler DocumentComplete;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_documentCompleteEventHandler = new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(DocumentCompleteEventHandler);
        m_autologinIEWindow = OpenIEWindowToURL("about:blank");
        m_autologinIEWindow.DocumentComplete += m_AutoLoginDocCompleteHandler;
        m_AutoLoginDocCompleteHandler = new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler);

        System.Console.Read();
    }

    public static void URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler(object senderObject, ref object objectTwo /* not sure what this argument is for */)
    {
        //Something
    }

    private static void DocumentCompleteEventHandler(object senderObject, ref object objectTwo /* not sure what this argument is for */ )
    {
           //Something
    }
}
```

The IE Window opens up with blank page as needed but the event is never fired up, ofcourse I am doing something wrong as I am super new and probably my first code in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the code simple and try as said below. It is working...

You can notice the document complete event handling.

Look into comments for explanation.

```
    static void Main()
    {

        //DECLARE INTERNET EXPLORER OBJECT
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer m_autologinIEWindow = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();

        //ASSOCIATE HANDLER TO DOCUMENT COMPLETE EVENT
        m_autologinIEWindow.DocumentComplete += URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler;

        //NAVIGATE THE URL
        m_autologinIEWindow.Navigate("about:blank");
        m_autologinIEWindow.AddressBar = true;
        m_autologinIEWindow.Visible = true;

    }

    //HANDLER DEFINITION
    public static void URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler(object senderObject, ref object objectTwo /* not sure what this argument is for */)
    {
        //Something
    }
```